# How to use a list as an argument in a function in R

Tags: r

`myfunction<-function(x){if (x=="g"){g_var<-x g_nvar<-length(g_var)} return(g_nvar)}`

I have written the above script to obtain specific elements out of a list. The argument x will be a list when I will call upon this function but R does not consider x as a list. How can I write a function such that when I provide a list, my output are the elements that I have specified in the function?

```
m  
[[1]]
[[1]] [[1]]
[1] "g" "g" "h" "g" "g" "g" "k" "l" 

[[2]]
[[2]] [[1]]
[1] "g" "h" "k" "k" "l" "g"
```

Expected result

```
[[1]] 5       # No. of g

[[2]] 2       # No. of g
```

Similarly I would like to obtain numbers for h,k and l also. I am putting m as x while calling the function.

For eg:- myfunction (m)

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example so we can test your code

Comment: Can you please provide EXAMPLE DATA and DESIRED OUTCOME to your question?

Comment: I think this is answered already here on SO. Some hints: look into `?lapply` to work with lists and check `sum(x == "g")` as a conversion of logical to 0 and 1 to get the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is somewhat complicated by the fact that your `m` is not simply a list of character vectors, but, in your example, a list of 2 lists of 1 vector of characters, as would be generated by

```
m = list(strsplit("gghgggkl", ""), strsplit("ghkklg", ""))
```

If we want `myfunction` to operate on this data structure, we have to refer to the component of the length-1-lists with the operation `[[1]]` (see `x[[1]]` below), and, as loki suggested, we can use `lapply` to work on all components of the outer list, and `sum` with a logical expression to obtain the desired count:

```
myfunction = function(m) lapply(m, function(x) sum(x[[1]]=='g'))
myfunction(m)
```

result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 2
```